# Bi-directional level shifter for serial communications

Tags: serial, level-shifting, logic-level

I want to know if I need to use a bi-directional level converter to send data from an ESP32 to a 5V display, using serial communications (TX and RX).

I understand the serial communication is uni-directional over the level shifter would need to be bi-directional since the TX from ESP32 to the display's RX is going from 3.3V to 5V, and then the TX pin from the display to the ESP32's RX pin is going from 5V to 3.3V, hence the bi-directional level shifter.

I was therefore thinking of using the [image]

[from Sparkfun](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12009?_ga=2.105064646.496563580.1634201205-1764319356.1630866786).
It is correct that I would need a bi-directional level shifter and if the one below will suffice for a baud rate o 9600.

Comment: Are RX and TX the same common pin at each end?

Comment: @Andyaka what do you mean?

Comment: A bidirectional level shifter is required when a single pin can operate as TX then switch to RX then back and forth. Does your circuit need to implement that?

Comment: @Andyaka arrghhh no the TX will always be TX and Rx will always be RX for each device

Comment: Then you don't need a bidirectional level shifter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading the blurb on the SparkFun board you linked to, it will be fine for the job, as long as the signals are quite slow, up to a few hundred kilohertz at best. That translator relies on pull-up resistors, which are not really suitable for faster signals. 9600 baud will be OK. This is how you'd wire it up:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpWAiL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are *not* correct when you state that you need a bi-directional level shifter, because the signals are not bi-directional. What you have is two uni-directional signals.

Read up on [I<sup>2</sup>C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I%C2%B2C) for an example of bi-directional signalling, where device pins can act as both inputs and outputs. In your application, I assume TX is always an output, and RX is always an input.

In your application you could get away with two unidirectional translators, one to shift a 5V output down to 3.3V suitable for the other device's input, and the other to go from 3.3V output to a 5V signal for the other device's input.

That might look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOKVHK.png)</sup>

Translator U1 has an input expecting 0V or 5V, but outputs only a 0V or 3.3V signal. U2 should take a 3.3V level input and output a 5V version.

There are many ICs you can use to shift between signal levels. Check out the [74LVC125](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74lvc125a.pdf?ts=1634219286379), [CD4504](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4504b.pdf?ts=1634219488759) for example. If you wish to convert 3.3V output signals to 5V, any 74HCTxx gate will do the trick, like the [74HCT08](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct08.pdf?ts=1634212114898) or [74HCT32](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct32.pdf?ts=1634220047788). You could even invert, using a [74HCT04](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct04.pdf) or [74HCT00](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74hct00.pdf).

The main advantages of using dedicated ICs like these to perform level shifting, rather than a MOSFET with pull-up resistors (like the SparkFun board), are speed and power. They'll be able to switch much faster, at several megahertz, with sharper transistions, while being able to sink *and* source much more current.

Up to a few tens or hundreds of kilohertz, the SparkFun board will work just fine, and you only need one unit.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I will rather just buy the BSS138 FETs and make my own, and it will cost less than to buy those ICs. In fact I will still inlcude those ICs in my PCB as a backup incase those FETs run out.

Comment: So I cannot just use one IC for this. SInce one IC is been used for 3.3V to 5V and then another IC is been for 5V to 3.3V. Gees thats alot of space for these ICs needed on the PCB and alot of wasted pins on the ICs.

Comment: @Joey, yeah, that's the problem with ICs in this role. If you had an 8-bit wide bus that you needed to translate, then you could justify using ICs, but in this case it's a lot smaller and easier to go with the SparkFun module, or discrete MOSFETs/resistors. Having said that, I'm sure there's a bidirectional translator out there suitable for your application, but I can't think of one off the top of my head.

Comment: is there any reason why I cannot connect some LEDs on the LV side of the module to see when info is going or coming in?

Answer (score 2):

No you don't need a bi-directional level shifter for two unidirectional signals. For 9600 bps UART comms that level shifter might work but in theory that's not a correct kind of level shifter. It is mainly meant for level shifting I2C bus.

Comment: what level shifter would be best

Comment: @Joey I don't know what your specs are for "best", and that would depend on many factors, including if the 5V display 5V data input is logic level compatible with 3.3V output so then best is a direct connection with wire.

Comment: The display will not function with 3.3V. I have tested that. And the tx line of the display goes from 0 to approx 5V so this will damge the RX pin of the esp32 for sure. Will a simple resistor divder work for this baud rate of 9600 or do I need to use someting else?

Comment: @Joey note, that "you don't need" in the answer does not mean "you can't use it". As Justme pointed out, this shifter should work OK at 9600, and it is cheap. Also, after you made sure it works for you, you can duplicate 2 channels of it on your own pcb for a compact solution with only 2 fets and 4 resistors. A lot of Adafruit boards are made exactly like that.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement already provided correct answers, here are some options for you to consider:

- You can replicate 2 channels of Sparkfun shifter on your own board, using 2 FETs and 4 resistors;
- You can use dual FET chip to reduce number of components to 5, as it is done for example [here](https://opencircuit.shop/product/Logic-Level-Shifter.-4-Channel.-Bidirectional);
- You can further reduce footprint by using resistor array, for a total of 2 components.
- Finally, you can go as low as a single component solution with dedicated 2-bit voltage translators like [TXS0102](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txs0102.pdf) or [TXB0102](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/txb0102.pdf) (at your speeds you probably will be OK without bypass and OE control components). Can't get any simpler than this.

Comment: Thanks but the TXB0102, the price is by far the most expensive.... :)

Comment: [$1.10](https://www.mouser.ca/ProductDetail/Texas-Instruments/TXS0102DCTR?qs=BWabSxB1G9cell1mrpKPvA%3D%3D) is expensive? It is half of the Sparkfun board price

Comment: Not the Sparkfun board. The BSS138 fet is cheaper than the TXS IC